# what is this line of code does? "description = ((string[])result[0])[2];"

Tags: c#

I have a sql database and I want to use specific column of it. Code below  shows the matches at the third column I just want to know what exactly `((string[])result[0])[2]` does in the code.

**Note**: "SingleSelectWhere" function choose those records that match the word of "bag" in the "word" column.

```
db.OpenDB("English.db");
ArrayList result = db.SingleSelectWhere("petdef", "*", "word", "=", "'bag'");
if(result.Count > 0)
{
    description = ((string[])result[0])[2];
}
db.CloseDB();
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: it's not unboxing because it's not converting to a value type. It's a simple reference type cast. What I'd like to know is why anybody is using non-generic `ArrayList` in 2015.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: it's not unboxing anything, only value types are boxed when using `ArrayList` (that's why it's better to use its generic counterpart, `List<T>`, to avoid boxing and casting). Casting in this case is very cheap (only a couple of sanity checks). But even more problematic than boxing is the loss of compile-time type safety, because you cannot be sure which type of elements the `ArrayList` is actually storing until you try to cast.

Comment: I feel surely that you are not asking the Stack Overflow community to manually interpret code that the compiler and debugger can interpret for you. Unfortunately, that's what your question looks like you are asking. Please improve the question so that it is clear what you're actually asking. What _specific_ problem do you have? Please provide a [mcve] that reliably reproduces that problem.

Comment: It selects the 3rd word from the first set of results. Blindly assuming there will be >= 3 words in that set.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - this API clearly has to deal with multiple types in a way that generics can't. Dynamic might be the better choice in 2015.

Comment: @Henk: From what I can see his method always returns a list of string arrays - i.e. a `List<string[]>` ought to do. Even if it could return a list of other types I'd still make it a `List<object>` just for the sake of consistency. I don't think I'd make the method return `dynamic` though - the user can use dynamic if they really really want to but in this case I don't see a reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what code does, just try to split it into some more "readable" code. If we take this line: `description = ((string[])result[0])[2];` we can do:

```
var result1 = result;
var result2 = result[0];
var result3 = (string[])result2;
var description = result3[2].
```

If you set a breakpoint to the first line, just start debugging and see what every step does / the variable contains. Just as a tip.

The answer: it takes the array/list with the name `result` and return the first element. Than you cast it to a string-array and finally select the thrid element (zero based index!). Hope this helps.